# Don't hide action bar in Safari for ios?

Tags: ios, mobile, responsive-design, safari

I have my menu in fixed bottom of the site for mobile devices to make it more reachable for your thumb.

But have run in to a problem in Safari. Cause when you scroll down, the bar disappears. And when you then press the "Menu" button on my website, nothing more happens except that the Safari action bar slides up from the bottom and also moves my menu up and away from where you had your thumb.

Is there any way to like keep the action bar up or keep it hidden? Or any other way to deal with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given a layout like this :

```
        <div className="App">
            <header></header>
            <main></main>
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
```

You can use this CSS to force the bottom nav bar to stay open.  This should give a nice footer that's outside the dreaded Safari Mobile dead-zone.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {position: fixed;}
.App {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
header {
    flex: 0 0 5rem;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
main {
    width: 100vw;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

I also recommend using the body-scroll-lock npm module to make your `main` tag scrollable and turning off body scrolling.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock